# How to ask a question so it does not get taken down

Tags: support, questions

How should I ask questions on this site? If I give all of the information and details I have, which sometimes is not a lot, my question gets taken down. Is there a guideline on how to ask a question so that it can be answered and not taken down?

Comment: What questions have you asked before? If you provide links we can comment on them even if they are deleted. Otherwise check out the [help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - if you want more specific help, please link us your questions as Robert mentioned

Answer (score 13):

You've asked two questions until now, and both were blatantly off-topic. It then doesn't matter if you included all the details or not. **Both** of those questions also got the same comment explaining that:

> Hi jlainez, welcome to [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com)! I'm not sure which search brought you here but the problem you describe will not be answered on this specific site. To get an answer from users that have the expertise about the topic of your question you'll have to find and then re-post on the [proper site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Check [How to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on the target site to make sure your post is acceptable. Your question is definitely off-topic on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) and is better deleted here

If after that you still aren't feeling like you fully understand, a few more links can be found at:

- The help center page on [closed-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)
- The help center page on [what not to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)